# Why does my app exceed 300mb when it should only be around 70mb?

Tags: android, apk

A work app I am working on is currently being generated at over 300mb, when in reality it should be around 70mb. I'm aware of the changes Android made whereby native libraries were not being compressed but the size of the APK being generated seems extreme to me. Setting extractNativeLibs="true" seems to have no effect either as i've tried this. below link is a screenshot to show what's obviously causing the issue but I'm stuck on what else I could try to compress the file further?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXPrr.png)

Answer (score 0):

The native libraries you're pulling are huge, compressed or not. Just the library **libtwilio** is taking 85 MB, then it's present for 4 different device architectures so I'm not surprised the total size is around 300MB.

You should be using the [App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#split_apks) so that the libraries of only one architecture is sent to each device of your users. This will considerably reduce the size of the APK that your users are downloading (the size of the App Bundle will still be big, but that only affects what you upload to the Play Console).

Note that even with App Bundle, you'll still be around 100 MB per split APK, so make sure that you really need this library. If it's not a core feature of your app, you can also consider extracting as a [dynamic feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/play-feature-delivery) so it's only downloaded by your app when the user needs the feature. That would further reduce the size of the initial download.